# Invalid login attempt when trying to access a valid account ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have my ASP.NET Core project on my PC and everything there works perfectly.

Recently I transferred my SQL databases from the PC to my laptop to see what would happen if I sent my project to someone. I have two databases but in this question, I want to focus on the database that stores user information.

When I try to sign in with an account from my PC everything works and I am able to login to my account, but when I try to do the same on my laptop I get `Invalid Login Attempt`, here is my function that checks the login:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code or maybe with the database itself?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I try to sign in with an account from my PC everything works and
> I am able to login to my account, but when I try to do the same on my
> laptop I get Invalid Login Attempt.

As per your shared code snippet it has appeared that within your login OnPostAsync method the result varibale returning `IsNotAllowed` property value as true or anything other than Succeeded,RequiresTwoFactor or IsLockedOut   and for these scenario you would get "Invalid login attempt" meaning first three conditions got failed.

I have successfully reproduced your issue as you can have a look below:

[image]

> There something wrong with the code or maybe with the database
> itself?

**Possible Reasons:**

It might be encountered for numerous reasons. Please double check following configuration what you have within your project:

**1.** Check correct database connection string:

As you said you have two database make sure you are connecting to the right database within your project. In your appsetting.json file double check following values if they are correct.

[image]

**2.** Make sure you have correct user:

The user you are trying to login ensure that is in your database table which can be found in AspNetUser table.

[image]

**3.** Check AspNetUsers Table EmailConfirmed Value:

Within AspNetUsers table you would seen a column EmailConfirmed. Its very cricial for your scenario. If you set that true in that case if you don't verify your email before login then login attempt would get failed.

[image]

**4.** RequireConfirmedAccount value in Program.cs file:

Within your program.cs file what value have you set for [RequireConfirmedAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinoptions.requireconfirmedaccount?view=aspnetcore-7.0) its related to "Invalid Login Attempt". If you set true thats mean you need to verify your account before login but you can set that false as well. You can do that as following:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**Note:**  It will allow you to login without verifying email account.

**5.** Check if you are getting result.Succeeded = true:

Your login will not be valided unless you wouldn't get result.Succeeded = true as following:

[image]

**Note:** If still getting same issue and  would like to know more details on [identity Log in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#log-in) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#log-in)

Comment: Thanks a lot, The problem was with the connection string and it's odd, yesterday I tried putting the connection string and it didn't work.
But now I have another problem which I will open another question soon if I want to find a solution to. Now when I try to register a new user it ways that its username has already been taken which obviously, is not.

Comment: Thanks.  Setting EmailConfirmed to true in the aspnetusers table fixed it for me.

Comment: Glad to know that you found it helpful.